# Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What does John 20:31 tell us about the intended audience of John’s gospel?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13012/what-does-john-2031-tell-us-about-the-intended-audience-of-john-s-gospel)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is Tamar "more righteous" than Judah?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13027/why-is-tamar-more-righteous-than-judah)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What were the translators of the LXX thinking in rendering “virgin” in Isaiah 7:14?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13165/what-were-the-translators-of-the-lxx-thinking-in-rendering-virgin-in-isaiah-7)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can the translation of δοξης as "glory" in Romans 3:23 be justified?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13220/how-can-the-translation-of-%ce%b4%ce%bf%ce%be%ce%b7%cf%82-as-glory-in-romans-323-be-justified)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Psalm 23:6 correct translation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/psalm-236-correct-translation)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What does it mean for Elisha to want "a double portion" from Elijah?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/what-does-it-mean-for-elisha-to-want-a-double-portion-from-elijah)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Calculating months and weeks in the Mosaic Law](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13260/calculating-months-and-weeks-in-the-mosaic-law)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Leviticus 25:46 meaning of Israelite brethren](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/leviticus-2546-meaning-of-israelite-brethren)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Isaiah 7:15: to whom does this verse refer?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13135/isaiah-715-to-whom-this-verse-refers)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is stewardship of the earth a modern interpretation?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/is-stewardship-of-the-earth-a-modern-interpretation)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---